OpenCore Sonoma glitched, can't login
I have Sonoma installed on an iMac with Opencore. It will boot to the login screen, but putting in my credentials just has the prompt disappear with the wine country wallpaper still visible. Any keystroke at this point gets me the thud sound. The cursor is still movable.
If I put in deliberately incorrect credentials, it rejects them, and I have another opportunity to try again.
Because I have Opencore installed, when it boots I get the disk selection menu before the Apple icon and progress bar. It only shows the hard disk, unless I have a recovery usb stick plugged in, then both show.
Other Google results suggest that re-running the patcher should fix this issue... but re-running it when I can't login is a bit of a head-scratcher. I can get to a terminal from the recovery stick, but of course the only apps that run there are disk utility and so forth. Trying to start them from the command line just results in dylib errors.
I can start it with verbose mode, for all the good it does me. I can start it in single user mode as well. I can get to recovery mode with cmnd-R, which looks freakily different (it's an old iMac), but gives no better options. But I cannot seem to start it in safe mode to save my life. I've only got the bluetooth keyboard, though some search results suggest that shouldn't cause an issue. I've tried both shift keys, alone, and together. I've tried them as soon as I hear the chime, as soon as I click the disk selection icon, and as soon as I see the apple plus progress bar. I've even tried using recovery mode's terminal, and doing nvram boot-args="-x"... but that does not seem to stick through a reboot (though it's supposed to?).
Is this thing completely bricked? Can I somehoe get it to where I can run the patcher again?
